# reference a variable in serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework

I'm trying to define my serverless framework deployment bucket.

My serverless.yml looks like this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: us-east-1
  stage: dev

  deploymentBucket:
    name: ${self:environment.DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET} 
  environment:
    ${file(../evn.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json)}
```

and the evn.dev.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET": "myBucketName"
}
```

(both of these files have non-relevant parts removed)

I'm getting a "cannot resolve variable at "provicer.deploymentBucket.name" error when trying to deploy.

How do I reference the DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET variable in the serverless.yml file?

EDIT:  Other errors:

`${environment}:DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET`  -> `Could not locate deployment bucket. Error: The specified bucket is not valid`

`name: ${environment:DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET}1` -> `Unrecognized configuration variable sources: "environment"`

`name: ${self:provider.environment:DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET}`
and
`name: ${self:environment:DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET}`

-> `Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.deploymentBucket.name": Value not found at "self" source`

I was able to solve the problem with this:
`${file(../evn.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET}`

But 'reading' that file twice -- both here and in the 'environment' area seems to somewhat defeat the purpose of the environments area.

Comment: shouldnt it be `name: ${self:provider.environment.DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET} `